# Low code apps for React native mobile app

Tags: appium, mobile-automation

I am currently writing test cases in C# using Appium which involves very hardcore coding - ie writing code for many test cases that involve large amount of steps to be automated.

Are there any low code applications out that that will record automate the mouse actions but still be able to interact with API's ?

As the mobile app is still under development there will more features in the future and this will just add to the workload.

It would be great if there are some tools out there that utilises generative AI like Co-pilot for test automation :)